# SAML Azure mappings

Tags: azure, saml

I'm trying to setup SocialCast to use SSO against Azure AD.  I have everything working except I'm unable to map the fields for first name, last name, and email address.  I know authentication is working because the logs on Azure confirm it, but I know I'm unable to pass names and email addresses because the test from SocialCast has blanks where there should be a name

This is what I need to fill out

[image: SC screen capture]

I've tried a bunch of different things in those fields, but none of them seem to work.

Here's a screenshot of the test from Socialcast

[image: SC cap]

Comment: `givenName` and `mail` look right but the AD attribute for "last name" is `sn`.

Comment: I tried that originally, but came away with the same issue...just a blank box.